# Worker Activity Not Updating in Twilio Taskrouter

Tags: php, twilio

According to the documentation:

> When TaskRouter assigns the Worker a Task, it will automatically move the Worker to an unavailable Activity, so that the Worker is not assigned new Tasks while they are occupied. On completion of their work, the Worker can be moved to an available Activity to begin accepting new Tasks again.

However, when Taskrouter assigns a task to a worker in my app, the calls route to the worker just fine, but the worker's Activity isn't updating. Also, even though there is a postWorkActivitySid specified when the task is assigned, the Worker's Activity never gets updated when the call completes either.

This doesn't make any sense to me, and no errors are thrown.

Comment: Do you have [TaskRouter multitasking](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/multitasking) set up on your workspace? Can you share your workspace config, including the available Activities with their availabilities?

Comment: For others finding this issue. Looking at the link to the docs that @philnash has provided, it shows that when Multitasking is enabled the worker's activity state does not change.